# Vuetify + Inertia + Typescript

Tags: typescript, vuetify.js, inertiajs

I am using Vuetify and Inertia, with Typescript.

I need to pass shared data to the items prop of a vuetify AutoComplete component :

```
<v-autocomplete :items="$page.props.countries"></v-autocomplete>
```

But TS tells me :

> Type unknown is not assignable to type readonly any[] | undefined

The `countries` list is an array of objects.
How can I type it correctly ?

Thanks

Comment: The error tells you.  countries should be `any[]`.  If you have a specific type for the object the array contains, e.g. "CountryType" it can be typed as `CountryType[]` which will also work.

Comment: Yes but I don't know how to write it into the Vue template. Could you give me the syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supplying types in the template is done with the `as` keyword

```html
<v-autocomplete :items="($page.props.countries as any[])">
```